# How can I calculate the origin of a scale transformation, given the starting and ending coords and dimensions?

Tags: geometry, transformation

**Background:**

I have two sets of coordinates/dimensions.  One for the red rectangle and one for the blue rectangle, as shown below.  The blue rectangle is quite simply the red rectangle transformed by a given scale factor.

[image]

**Question:**

Given that I know the coordinates for both the starting red rectangle and the resulting blue rectangle as well as the scale factor, how can I calculate the origin for this transformation?

e.g.

if the red rectangles coordinates/dimensions are as follows:

```
topleftX = 600
topleftY = 600
width = 400
height = 300
```

And the resulting blue rectangle needs to have the coordinates as follows:

```
 topleftX = 200
 topleftY = 200
 width = 2000
 height = 1500
```

I can calculate simply that the scale factor is **5**

Given that scale factor, how can I calculate the origin of this transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is meant by "origin" of the transformation, but you certainly translated.  The translation is the vector from the center of the red rectangle to the center of the blue.

Comment: My apologies for my lack of math etiquette. I am able to calculate the translation, no problem.  What I need is to be able to calculate a point on the red rectangle that when scaled by the given factor, would result in creating the blue rectangle.

Comment: Ok, so you want the full transformation matrix $T$ such that you can take a point $p_r$ and find the corresponding blue point $\begin{bmatrix}p_b & 1 \end{bmatrix} = T \begin{bmatrix} p_r \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $ ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find what is called the "centre of enlargement."

Choose any corner on the blue rectangle and the corresponding corner on the red rectangle. Draw a straight line through them. Repeat with another corner. The point of intersection of these two lines is the centre of enlargement.

Answer (score 0):

The center of the red rectangle appears to be located at $p_{red} = \begin{bmatrix} 800 \\ 750 \end{bmatrix}$, and the blue rectangle at $p_{blue} = \begin{bmatrix} 1200 \\ 950 \end{bmatrix}$.  So your amount of translation is given by 
$$
t = p_{blue} - p_{red}
$$

Comment: thanks, please see my comment.  I am able to calculate the translation but this is not what I need.  Sorry for my poort articulation